# Ordering table by hour

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to sort this table by hour, from 19 to 18 next day.

```
Hour  HourCount
0     234
1     322
2     333
3     433
4     544
5     589
6     675
7     688
8     734
9     789
10    821
11    892
12    922
13    954
14    987
15    996
16    1007
17    1068
18    1121
19    0
20    36
21    78
22    126
23    189
```

How can I do it? Is there any method that I can order by set of numbers?

Comment: Show us your table design. How do you differentiate one day from the next?

Comment: The data is inserted into this table depend of the time is produced on the machine and it use datepart(hh,TransTimeStamp). So the rest of the time is not recorded. It is stored procedure actually which only builds day from 19 to 18, there would not be more days or hour then the example table. But it could be less hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  TABLE1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN HOUR > 17 THEN -1
              ELSE HOUR
         END
```

Comment: Sorry don't get your answer? What 'set some condition'?

Comment: If hour exceeding 17 what will you do.

Comment: Use `CASE WHEN HOUR > 18 THEN -1  ELSE HOUR END`.[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b4080/4)

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. I dont want to do anything I just want to order number like that: 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1 ... 17, 18

Comment: @Whistler Try above query now